# How to calculate the following inverse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to calculate the inverse of matrix $B=[b_{ij}]_{m.m}$, where
$b_{ii}=x_i+b$ and $b_{ij}=b~(i\neq j)$,$x_i>0$ and $b<0$ for $1\leq i,j\leq m$. I applied  the Sherman-Morrison formula.

The Sherman–Morrison formula states that: Suppose ${\displaystyle A}$ is an invertible square matrix and ${\displaystyle u}$, ${\displaystyle v}$ are column vectors. Suppose furthermore that ${\displaystyle 1+v^{T}A^{-1}u\neq 0}$ . Then 
$$ (A+uv^{T})^{-1}=A^{-1}-{A^{-1}uv^{T}A^{-1} \over 1+v^{T}A^{-1}u}.$$ But in my problem may ${\displaystyle 1+v^{T}A^{-1}u= 0}$. Can you suggest other methos?

Comment: "But in my problem may $1+v^{T}A^{-1}u= 0$" - then the new matrix is singular and thus not invertible.

Comment: "If ${\displaystyle 1+v^{T}A^{-1}u= 0}$, Then $(A+uv^{T})$ is singular". Is correct?

Comment: Yes.$\phantom{}$

Comment: You can use pseudo inverse